# Why my ionic app does not show data from the DB in Android?

Tags: php, android, mysql, ionic-framework

I have a simple Ionic app that shows some data from a PHP service.
The PHP connects to the database and returns a JSON.

This is the code of the service (in the url, instead of "MyIP" is written my real IP):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiserviceService {
  apiURLCarreras = 'http://MyIP/vaspa/servicioPlanes.php';
constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getCarreras(){
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiURLCarreras}`);
  }
}
```

This works great in my PC! I can see the list of items:
[list of items in PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HEAH.png)

But in my Android device, when I run the app I can´t see any item. The list is empty.

However, if I put the URL of the service (MyIP/vaspa/servicioPlanes.php) in the web browser, I can see the JSON with all the items: [list of items Android web browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W57mo.jpg)

I have Windows 10 with Xampp 7.2.32 (configured to support external connections)
The Android device is a Xiaomi Redmi Note 6 Pro.

Any clues what is happening? What is the mistake? I think might be a problem from the smartphone but I don't have another in this moment.

Comment: Did you turn off the firewall of your laptop?